# Не находит драйвер com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, mysql, база-данных, mysqlconnector

Не находит драйвера java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

драйвер подключен,
сервер MySQL работает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `драйвер подключен` - хм. Был бы подключен - не было бы ошибки. Что вы тут имеете ввиду? Как именно вы его пытаетесь подключить? Ну и покажите ваш `build.gradle` файл.

Comment: Судя по скриншоту - вы настроили соединение в db плагине самой intellij idea. Но это не то, вам нужно его настроить в зависимостях проекта. Так что показывайте ваш `build.gradle`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `build.gradle` в секцию `dependencies` нужно добавить:

```
dependencies {
    // тут другие существующие зависимости 
    // ...
    runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.25'
}
```

Если для сборки в IDE вы не пользуетесь интеграцией с gradle (что очень зря), до добавьте вручную зависимость на jar файл с драйвером в `Project Settings -> Modules -> ваш модуль -> Dependencies`:

[image: Добавление зависимости в проект IntelliJ IDEA]

Comment: Работает, спасибо хороший человек